# Encode audio float opus c

Tags: c, encode, opus

I'm trying to encode & decode audio with opus, but when I'm running my code the function opus_encode_float return -1.

```
   int opuscode(float *sound)
    {
    unsigned char data[1000000];
    int *error;
    int ini;
    opus_int32  rate = SAMPLE_RATE;
    int size = opus_encoder_get_size(CHANNELS);
    OpusEncoder *op = opus_encoder_create(rate, 2, OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP, error);
    opus_encoder_ctl(op, OPUS_GET_BANDWIDTH(&rate));
    int  len = opus_encode_float(op, sound, rate, data, rate);
    printf("%i ici ", len);
    int decodesize = opus_decoder_get_size(CHANNELS);
    OpusDecoder *dop = opus_decoder_create(rate, 2, error);
}
```

Comment: You're passing it an out of range argument. `#define OPUS_BAD_ARG          -1`

Comment: Don't allocate 1 million bytes on the stack.